# Не могу преобразовать requests запрос

Tags: python, web-scraping

Код

```
URL = "https://garantex.io/trading/btcrub"
response = requests.get(URL)
html = response.text
result = dict(json.loads(html))
print(result)
```

ругается `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`

Основная цель вытащить значения на картинке, но я пока не могу даже запрос нормально обработать.
Буду признателен за любую помощь или в каком направлении искать.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну в ответ же html приходит, а вы его как json пытаетесь декодировать. Для разбора html используйте например lxml.html или BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Ага, понял. Тогда вопрос есть ли способ преобразовать данный html в json? И вообще возможно ли это учитывая наличия "мусора" в html

Comment: Там вообще json нет, нечего преобразовывать в json. Просто вытаскиваете значения, например, по классу тега td, вычищаете оттуда оставшиеся теги, собираете, например, в список списков или в датафрейм.

Answer (score 0):

json.loads(html) работает со строкой в которой лежит json, у тебя там лежит html страницы. Изучи библиотеки для парсинга и ими обрабатывай входящие данные.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).